# GRU in DeepLearning4J

Tags: deep-learning, deeplearning4j, recurrent-neural-network, gated-recurrent-unit

I am trying to find a GRU implementation within DeepLearning4J but cannot seem to find one.  Does anyone know if GRU's are implemented within DL4J?  If so can you please direct me to an example.  If not, is this on their roadmap anywhere?

Thanks

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but a TensorFlow implementation is found here https://www.data-blogger.com/2017/08/27/gru-implementation-tensorflow/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't find one because there isn't one. It's not on our roadmap because it doesn't have a clear ROI compared to LSTMs.
We have both LSTMs and Bidirectional.

In general, we've only needed one and people have bene satisfied with that.